# JAVA: 128-bit key to String problem and back

Tags: java, string, key, base64, aes

I have created a SecretkeySpec object wich contains a 128 bit key.
I would like to have this key in a String(this string needs to be put back in to the original key later), so i use Base64 encoding.

This is how my key looks in raw format from the byte array into chars:

```
*P??? ?ukL|?~
```

So I take the bytes and encode it like this.

```
byte[] okay = Base64.encode(eF.getSpec().getEncoded());
```

Now when i translate it into chars i get:

```
S2xEa3Ara0o5blVGYTB3WkRIeUZmZz09DQo=
```

Now i want to have my key back restored to it's original format from the base64 encoded array.

```
String dkey = "S2xEa3Ara0o5blVGYTB3WkRIeUZmZz09DQo=";

byte[] key = null;
key = dKey.getBytes();
key = Base64.decode(key);
```

Now when i check the result i get:

```
DKlDkp+kJ9nUFa0wZHyFfg==
```

instead of:

```
*P??? ?ukL|?~
```

As you can see this is not the result i hoped to see.
I surely made a novice mistake, and forgive me for that but i am relativaly new to programming.
I would appreciate it if someone could give me a working example of transforming
the 128 bit key to and from readable format, and perhaps an explanation where i went wrong with thinking.

And i apologize for any spelling mistakes, English is not my native language.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What `Base64` class are you using? Is it from the Apache Codec library?

Comment: What does `eF.getSpec().getEncoded()` do? I don't see a similar call in the decoding part.

Comment: @casablanca: I *presume* it's the [`getEncoded()` method of the `SecretKeySpec` class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/crypto/spec/SecretKeySpec.html#getEncoded%28%29). If that's the case, then it should simply return the raw bytes representing the key.

Comment: Yes it is, import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

Comment: @casablanca: Sorry for that, but Adam is right. that is the key in raw bytes. in my decrypting part i have my string and i need to put it back in a raw byte array that represent my new key(wich should be identical to my original key but in my case it's not).

Comment: @Rohan: If you encode/decode the key using the [`Hex` class](http://commons.apache.org/codec/api-release/index.html) (also in Commons Codec), do things work? See [`encodeHexString`](http://commons.apache.org/codec/api-release/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html#encodeHexString%28byte%5b%5d%29) and [`decodeHex`](http://commons.apache.org/codec/api-release/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html#decodeHex%28char%5b%5d%29).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
S2xEa3Ara0o5blVGYTB3WkRIeUZmZz09DQo=
```

decodes to

```
KlDkp+kJ9nUFa0wZDHyFfg==.
```

Is the extra D at the beginning a copy and paste error?

```
KlDkp+kJ9nUFa0wZDHyFfg==
```

in turn is a valid base64 string that decodes to some binary data. So it seems that you are doing the encoding twice.

> Now when i translate it into chars i get

How exactly are you doing that? Is there another base64 encoding involved in that step?

Comment: I check it with a for loop: String stringkey = "";
               for(byte forbyte :  key){
                char forchar = (char) forbyte;
                 stringkey += forchar;
                }
               System.out.println(stringkey); i check my code twice, there is only 1 call to Base64.encode and only 1 call to  Base64.decode. and that indeed seems to be a typo.

Comment: @Rohan: Perhaps you should edit your question to include *all* pertinent code.

Comment: indeed his K1Dk etc does decode to what looks like the original key which starts with (*P). can Rohan check what comes out of `eF.getSpec().getEncoded()`?

Comment: @lijie Indeed, decoding my decoded String does give me my original 128bit key, i do not understand why that is though. as my knowledge with encoding in general is very weak. eF.getSpec().getEncoded() gives me *P??? ?ukL|?~ translated into chars.

Answer (score 0):

You had some errors in the code (presuming you wrote it from the top of your head). This looks like a working version. Note that using these internal classes is not very clever (here I would prefer to use Apache Commons Codecs library, for example and its `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64` class).

```
package edu.sasik.test.encoding;

import com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dv.util.Base64;

public class TestBase64 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String base64Str = Base64.encode("Hello World!".getBytes());
    System.out.println(base64Str);
    byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(base64Str);
    System.out.println(new String(bytes));
  }

}
```

Output:

```
SGVsbG8gV29ybGQh
Hello World!
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Jiri, Thanks for the reply but my case a litttle bit different then that, as i have a 128 bit key wich needs to be translated to a readable format. so indeed i encode it as i said above ( byte[] okay = Base64.encode(eF.getSpec().getEncoded());) eF.getSpec().getEncoded() is indeed the key, sorry for being unclear on that part. but when i decode it the result is not the same as my input.